# Cannot push TTTableViewController onto Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, three20, uitabbar

I have an app where I have a TTTableView Controller inside a Navigation Controller that is Insider a TabBar.

I want it so that if a user selects an item it will push another TTTableView with the items under that category.

The code I have is

```
-(void)didSelectObject:(id)object atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if ([object isKindOfClass:[TTTableMoreButton class]]) {
        [super didSelectObject:object atIndexPath:indexPath];
    } else {
        CategoryViewController *viewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController release];
    }
}
```

The CategoryViewController is setup as

```
@interface CategoryViewController : TTTableViewController
```

and the CategoryViewController.xib file has the datasource & delegate set to the files owner and the view set to the tableview and the tableview class is set to TTTableView.

When I run it I get the following error when selecting a row

```
2011-10-17 16:18:23.819 Biz Insider[34067:f803] -[CategoryViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c93d30
2011-10-17 16:18:23.820 Biz Insider[34067:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CategoryViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c93d30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1893052 0x157ed0a 0x1894ced 0x17f9f00 0x17f9ce2 0xb4cf2b 0xb4f722 0x9ff7c7 0x9ff2c1 0x9b61e 0xa0228c 0xa06783 0x9bb48 0x9b1301 0x1894e72 0x89192d 0x89b827 0x821fa7 0x823ea6 0x823580 0x18679ce 0x17fe670 0x17ca4f6 0x17c9db4 0x17c9ccb 0x1f88879 0x1f8893e 0x972a9b 0x273d 0x26b5)
terminate called throwing an exceptionCurrent language:  auto; currently objective-c
```

If I try and push another view (i have one with a webview on it) then it works fine, or if I go into interface builder and link the File Owner's "tableView" to the TTTableView object it will work fine and push the controller except the "Pull down to refresh" function wont work so I am assuming that the deletage isn't correct when doing it that way.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
I have a feeling that it has something to do with the following

```
-(id<UITableViewDelegate>)createDelegate {
    return [[[TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate alloc] initWithController:self] autorelease];
}
```

This sets the delegate to TTTableViewDragRefreshDelegate which implements the numberOfRowsInSection and all that junk. Is there another way to do this?

Cheers,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is an odd one, but I changed it from

```
CategoryViewController *viewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoryViewController" bundle:nil];
```

to

```
CategoryViewController *viewController = [[CategoryViewController alloc] init];
```

and it magically works now...dont ask me how or why.

There must have been something in the NIB that was messing it up, but I dont know how the whole layout is working now with no NIB.

Answer (score 0):

The log says that in your custom class `CategoryViewController` method `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` is not implemented and so it couldn't call it.

Check it and check types of its parameters.

Comment: I saw that but it shouldn't have to be implemented should it? Only If I am changing its functionality.

Comment: It should be implemented, of course. You should said how much rows you want to display

Comment: It works in the other views I have though, as far as I know the TTTableViewController uses the dataSource and passes those calls off to the dataSource. All of those functions are implemented int he dataSource.

Comment: The problem is that nor `CategoryViewController` nor `TTTableViewController ` implements that method in your case. That is.